# c# AssemblyInfo.cs "bug"

Tags: c#, .net-assembly

Can someone explain how to make assembly info correctly?

This is my AssemblyInfo.cs:

```
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("Title")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("Description")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("Mycompany")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("ProductName")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright ©")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCulture("")]

[assembly: ComVisible(true)]

[assembly: Guid("xxxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx")]    

[assembly: AssemblyVersion("1.0")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0")]
[assembly: NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute("en")]
```

and this is how it is shown in properties window:[image: Details]

You can see that Description and Language is not same as in AssemblyInfo.cs.

Also something is wrong with AssemblyCompany because when I open startup keys in ccleaner, company field is empty for my program...[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't find the details that quickly, but you set the _assembly_ information there (.NET), while not all of those properties are propagated to the _executable_ (Win32 PE). The Details tab shows the details of the latter. As for the Title / Description confusion: [**`AssemblyTitle`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assemblytitleattribute(v=vs.110).aspx): _"the information specified for this attribute appears on the Details tab of the Windows File Properties dialog box for the assembly. The property name is **File description**"_.

Comment: `NeutralResourcesLanguageAttribute` is for .net assemblies. The language property is for unmanaged use.

Comment: Looks like `AssemblyTitle("Title")` maps to File Description. That seems obvious just from the code and your screenshots.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Windows doesn't know beans about managed assembly attributes.  What you actually see is an *unmanaged resource* that's embedded in the assembly.  The C# compiler auto-generates it from the attribute values in your AssemblyInfo.cs file.  You can see it yourself with File + Open + File, select your .dll or .exe file.  Double-clicking the Version.1 resource opens the unmanaged resource editor, the one you use in a C++ project.

The mapping from managed attributes to that unmanaged version resource is imperfect.  Note for example that you cannot see the [AssemblyVersion] attribute value.  Extremely important in .NET, Windows only displays the [AssemblyFileVersion] attribute value.

And culture is certainly such an impedance mismatch.  A .NET assembly that contains code always has AssemblyName.CultureName set to "*".  Only satellite assemblies have a culture.  And title vs description, the unmanaged version resource has only one field that qualifies, they selected [AssemblyTitle] to map to that field.

You can create your own unmanaged version resource with a resource script, compile it with rc.exe.  You use Project + Properties, Application tab, Resource file radio button to tell the C# compiler about it.  You are unlikely to enjoy it much, constantly updating and recompiling the resource script to keep the version number in sync is going to wear you out quickly unless you can automate that.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Express so I don't have resource editor... Is there some tutorial where I can learn the proper way to set .exe properties (all programs on ccleaner picture have publisher name so there must be some "normal" and easy way to do this)?

Comment: It almost certainly shows you the publisher of the AuthentiCode certificate.  Yes, they are normal.  No, easy isn't exactly the right word.  Certificates cost money, you'll spend hundreds of dollars on them to have another company prove to your customer that you are trustworthy.